# Having multiple animals in the same field in foxes and rabbits simulation

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, jframe, jpanel, simulation

I'm making a new version of this foxes and rabbits Simulation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7KtfGELZsM

What I would like to do is be able to store multiple animals within the same square of the grid, not just one at a time. At the moment, Animals are stored in a 2d multidimensional array Animal[x][y] which if an animal is already in this location then it will replaced with the new animal. Perhaps this needs to be changed to a HashMap or something similar? For example -
 http://comscigate.com/HW/cs302/BlueJ/projects/chapter10/foxes-and-rabbits-v2/Field.java

Potentially something like this:

```
// Storage for the animals.
private List<Field> field;
private List<List<Animal>> animalsList;


public void place(Animal animal)
{
    Location location = animal.getLocation();
    animalsList = new ArrayList<List<Animal>>();
    field = new ArrayList<Animal>;
    field.add(Field(location.getRow(), location.getCol()));
    animalsList.add(field, animal);
}
```

Comment: For each cell, use some kind of `List` which can manage multiple `Animal` objects

Comment: So something like this:

`  // Storage for the animals.
  private List<Field> field;
  private List<List<Animal>> animalsList;


    public void place(Animal animal)
    {
        Location location = animal.getLocation();
        animalsList = new ArrayList<List<Animal>>();
        field = new ArrayList<Animal>;
        field.add(Field(location.getRow(), location.getCol()));
        animalsList.add(field, animal);
    }`

Comment: @NoDirection : Id like to see your Location class, then I could edit my solution so that its not only working for java.awt.Point

Comment: @NoDirection : basically the same. Only replace Point with Location, x with row and y with col

Answer (score 0):

Id use a simple storage system. Lets assume you have a 10*10 field :

- You need a `List<List<Animal>> list=new ArrayList<List<Animal>>();`
- You need 100 spaces that are all empty(well, you could also use an array) :

  ```
  for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
      list.add(new ArrayList<Animal>());
  }
  ```
- Your method :

  ```
  public void addAt(int x, int y, Animal a) {
      int w=10; //WIDTH
      int h=10; //HEIGHT
      List<Animal> animals_here=list.get(y*h+x);
      animals_here.add(a);
      list.put(y*h+x,animals_here);
  }
  ```
- if youd like to extract the position from an index :

  ```
  - x=index%h;
  - y=index/h; //Integer divison, no doubles/floats !
  ```

Another, probably easier accessable attempt would be a Map :

```
class Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
}

Map<Point,List<Animal>> map=new HashMap();
public void addAt(int x, int y,Animal a) {
    if (map.get(new Point(x,y))==null) {
        List<Animal> animals_here=new ArrayList<Animal>();
        animals_here.add(a);
        map.put(new Point(x,y),animals_here);
    }
    else {
        List<Animal> animals_here=map.get(new Point(x,y));
        animals_here.add(a);
        map.put(new Point(x,y),animals_here);
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Efficiency : 
CPU :
 - Solution 1 : Indices are calculated each time, not so easy acess
 - Solution 2 : Map is very fast.
RAM :
- Solution 1 : Less animals than cells : -, because you have unused cells
  More animals than cells : +, because almost every cell will be used and the keys havent to be stored
- Solution 2 : Less animals than cells : +, because they are saved with keys
                                                                        More animals than cells : -, because keys are always stored too

**About the code you provided on GitHub :**

- Make another class for the field.

  ```
  class Field {
      public Map<Point, List<Animal>> map;
      public int w,h;
      public Field(int w, int h) {
          this.w=w;
          this.h=h;
          map=new HashMap<Point, List<Animal>>();
      }
      public void addAnimal(int x, int y) {
          if (map.get(new Point(x, y)) == null) {
              List<Animal> animals_here = new ArrayList<Animal>();
              animals_here.add(animal);
              map.put(new Point(x, y), animals_here); //Set
          } 
          else {
              List<Animal> animals_here = map.get(new Point(x, y));
              animals_here.add(animal);
              map.put(new Point(x, y), animals_here); //Overwrite
          }
      }
      public List<Animal> animalsAt(int x, int y) { //If it returns null, there isnt an animal
          return map.get(new Point(x,y));
      }
      public void doStuff() {
          for (int x=0; x < w; x++) {
              for (int y=0; y < h; y++) {
                   List<Animal> animals_there=animalsAt(x,y);
                   if (animals_there != null) {
                        for (Animal a:animals_there) {
                         //Do your stuff
                        }
                   }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- The point class is only to store two values : x and y. You dont need anything more.

  ```
  class Point {
      public int x;
      public int y;
      public Point(int x, int y) {
          this.x=x;
          this.y=y;
      }
  }
  ```
- Dont make all vars private. Then you wont have to use getters and setters, you can access them easier.

***BUT I THINK ITS MAYBE EASIEST TO STORE THE POSITION IN EVERY ANIMAL((-)very memory inefficent, but since you're not going to have 1000000 animals, it will be enough)***

```
class Animal {
    public String type;
    public Location location;
    public Animal(String type, Location location) {
        this.type=type;
        this.location=location;
    }
}



//When you want to have specific methods(and vars) for different animals, create subclasses : 

class Lion extends Animal {
    public Lion(String type, Location location) {
        super(type,location);
    }
    public void live(List<Object> other_animals) {
        List<Integer> toRemove=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int index=0;
        for (Object o:other_animals) {
             if (o instanceof Mouse) {
                 Mouse m=(Mouse)o;
                 if (m.location.equals(this.location)) {
                     toRemove.add(index);
                 }
             }
             index++;
        }
    }
}

class Mouse extends Animal {
    public Mouse(String type, Location location) {
        super(type,location);
    }
}

//Your field : 
class Field {
    public List<Object> animals;
    public Field() {
        animals=new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    public void add(Object o) {
        animals.add(o);
    }
    public List<Object> getAt(Location l) {
        List<Object> animals_there=new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (Object o:animals) {
             if (((Animal)(o)).location.equals(l)) {
                 animals_there.add(o);
             }
        }
        return animals_there;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (map.get(new Point(x,y))==null) {` This line returns a NullPointer for me

Comment: This should mean you havent any animal at this location

Comment: Is this another separate class Point or is it replacing Field and the place method? Also x, y returns the size of the grid rather than the location of the Animal, if you look at the original place method - 
`public void place(Animal animal)
    {
        Location location = animal.getLocation();
        field[location.getRow()][location.getCol()] = animal;
    }`

Location is already available to us and stores the animal position within the grid not Field/Point. Would you be able to explain this for me?

Comment: @NoDirection : So, the idea of this is very easy : A map works like a dictionary. You have a Key(in this case, a Point is useful) and an assigned value, in this case, a list of animals. If you then attempt to get an element using map.get(Point key); , **there are  two possibilities : ** 1. It returns zero. Means the element isnt existing. Then youll have to create a new list, containing the animal you want to place, and insert it using map.put(Point key, List<Animal> value); 2.It returns something. Add your animal and insert the new list at the same position(overwrite the old)

Comment: It's returning null every time as Point(x,y) is a primitive, null is not a value that it can take on?

Comment: @NoDirection Point **isnt** a primitive https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html -> Youll have to import java.awt.Point;

Comment: **EDIT : Sorry, forgot initializing of map=new HashMap()**

Comment: Ah yes, thanks :) So how do I now get each animal out of it? 
`public Animal getObjectAt(Location location)
    {
        return getObjectAt(location.getRow(), location.getCol());
    }`

Comment: I think it has to be a list of animals ? `public List<Animal> getObjectAt(Point p) { return map.get(p); }`

Comment: I like what you have suggested in terms of the map, but I'm struggling to work out how I could use this to return two animals to on-top of each other at a certain location

Comment: @NoDirection : Its a map of lists. So any key(location) refers to a list(animals at this location)

Comment: You can then iterate through it. `for (Animal a:getObjectAt(new Location(0,0))) { }`

Comment: @NoDirection : Please have a look at my new edit, Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143430/discussion-between-user7185318-and-nodirection).